# Display only those results whose id matches the URL param

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a URL parameter gatewayId and I want to display only those objects whose id matches the parameter.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-receiver',
  templateUrl: './message-receiver.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-receiver.component.scss']
})
export class MessageReceiverComponent implements OnInit {
  data: {
    message: string,
    gatewayId: number
  }[] =
  [
    {message: "Message 1", gatewayId: 1},
    {message: "Message 2", gatewayId: 2},
    {message: "Message 3", gatewayId: 3},
    {message: "Message 4", gatewayId: 1},
    {message: "Message 5", gatewayId: 2},
    {message: "Message 6", gatewayId: 3}
  ]
```

```
<div>
    <div>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="goToGateway()">
            <span>&#8592;</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="sendMessage()" style="float: right;">Send message</button>
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let member of data">    
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li *ngIf="member.gatewayId === 1">{{member.message}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

(Here the filter is hardcoded so don't pay attention to that).

So if the URL is */1, I want to display only messages 1 and 4. I tried to do it with ActivatedRoute and ngFor/ngIf but can't get it done unfortunately.

Comment: how does `URL` looks like

Comment: *URL*/gatewayId. So gatewayId is the last part of the URL.

Comment: are you able to get the url param in the component?

Answer (score 0):

In you component.ts:

```js
gatewayId:number;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
if(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
      this.gatewayId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
}
```

In your component.html:

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="goToGateway()">
            <span>&#8592;</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="sendMessage()" style="float: right;">Send message</button>
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let member of data">    
       
        <li *ngIf="member.gatewayId === gatewayId">{{member.message}}</li>
            
    </ng-container>
</div>
```